# OpenBSD install trouble with screen resolution

Tags: installation, resolution, openbsd

I am installing OpenBSD on an old Dell Optiplex G620 with a 19 inch widescreen Viewsonic monitor. The problem is that the last line of the install program extends off the bottom of the screen; I can only see the top tips of the letters. This is the line where it prompts  you for user input and I can’t just go with return -> default for some values. OpenBSD autoinstalls from boot, so I can’t use some sort of switch to change the install program’s resolution and no auto confit mode on the Viewsonic fixes the problem. The Viewsonic occasionally pops up a message recommending I change the screen resolution to 1600 x 788, but how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Press the "Auto" button and select the automatic resolution adjustment.

Comment: Can you clarify what "Auto" button you're referring to?

Comment: This sort of worried - pressing Auto allowed Gnome to come up,but now there’s a conflict by which OpenBSD does not like the Viewsonic’s default screen res and logs me out if I try to change the res,run an Activity or put the cursor in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There are three little buttons under the Viewsonic screen. They allow you access to menus, one of which shrinks the screen vertically.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue when I was installing OpenBSD 6.8. Reducing the graphics memory in BIOS helped.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?